# How to export hive data to specified fields of mysql using sqoop?

Tags: mysql, hive, hdfs, sqoop

I have `field1, field2, field3` in hdfs, and `id(auto increment), field1, field2, field3, uptate_time(default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` in mysql table, I want to export the three fields in hdfs to mysql table which have five fields with two fields having default value. How to implement this in sqoop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `--columns "<comma separated column names>"` to export to selected columns.

As per sqoop [docs](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_syntax_4) in Table 29,

> You can select a subset of columns and control their ordering by using the `--columns` argument. This should include a comma-delimited list of columns to export. For example: `--columns "col1,col2,col3"`. Note that columns that are not included in the `--columns` parameter need to have either defined default value or allow NULL values. Otherwise your database will reject the imported data which in turn will make Sqoop job fail.